# Rebind the data in Gridview to show 50 and up instead of 1 and up

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

How do you rebind the data in Gridview to show 50 and up instead of 1 and up.

Starts from 1:

```
    Dim connStr, cmdStr As String
    Dim myDataSet As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    connStr = "connection string works"
    cmdStr = "SELECT * FROM table1;"
    Try
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Using myDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet)
                    dt = myDataSet.Tables(0)
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt
                    GridView1.DataBind()
                End Using
                conn.Close()
                cmd.Dispose()
                conn.Dispose()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

What do I need to change to start from 50 and up?

Answer (score 0):

Make your `DataTable` an enumerable object and then use LINQ's `.Skip()` function to get past the first 50 items, like this:

```
Dim filteredSet = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(50)
```

Now bind the `filteredSet` instead of `dt` to the grid view, like this:

```
GridView1.DataSource = filteredSet
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the most efficient choice would be to not select the data from the database by using a parametrized query where you pass in a starting value of some sort and the query only selects data occurring after this point.

Another option, which only takes a small adjustment to your code is to simply delete rows from the DataTable like so:

```
' remove the first 50 rows
For x As Integer = 1 To 50
    dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0)
Next
```